Ag-Grid Server side pagination with React: grid is resetted when an item is selected
Please go to this codesandbox example to reproduce the issue below.

Context

I am using Ag Grid to do server side pagination on a public paginated API (Pokemon one) as explained here, and display result in the table.
Moreover, I want to be able to select an item in the table, and display all selected items at the top (stored in React state).

Issue

My issue is :  if you change the page (for example 2nd one), and select an item in the table by clicking on it, the Grid component is re-rendered, and you are redirected to the first page! We should stay on the second page, no reason to re-render.

Temporary fix

I have managed it by using useCallback() on addItem function with empty dependency array, and memo on Grid component. But a new isue arises : eslint rule "exhaustive deps" is broken and we can have duplicated in the selected items list, that I want to avoid.
Any ideas how to handle that issue properly in React? Thank you!

Finally, I have found the proper way to do it with react. Please note that it does not concern ag-grid but  only react rendering mechanism.

addItem() BEFORE, not working (with duplicates we want to avoid):

  const addItem = useCallback((item: any) => {
    const exist = selectedItems.findIndex(
      (existingItem) => existingItem.name === item.name
    );
    if (exist === -1) {
      setSelectedItems((items) => items.concat(item));
    }
  }, []);


addItem() AFTER, working properly (without duplicates, and (I think) React oriented) :

 const addItem = useCallback((item: any) => {
      setSelectedItems((items) => {
        const exist = items.findIndex(
         (existingItem) => existingItem.name === item.name
        );
        if (exist === -1) {
          return items.concat(item);
        }
     return items;
     });
 }, []);

Codesandbox updated

You should change as below:
setSelectedItems((items) => [...items, item]);
setState should always be a new object instead of mutating the original one.

Thank you for your feedback, but the concat method that I use returns a new object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Indeed, my mistake.
It seems the real problem is the typical problem of closure. The selectedItems is kept the original value of lexical scope.
const addItem = useCallback((item: any) => {
setSelectedItems((items) => {
const exist = items.findIndex(
(existingItem) => existingItem.name === item.name
);
if (exist === -1) {
return items.concat(item);
}
return items;
});
}, []); // try to put selectedItems : not working anymore

  const addItem = useCallback((item: any) => {
setSelectedItems((items) => {
  const exist = items.findIndex(
    (existingItem) => existingItem.name === item.name
  );
  if (exist === -1) {
    return items.concat(item);
  }
  return items;
});

}, []); // try to put selectedItems : not working anymore

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
